# Translation of Hilbert's paper on sums of squares

Tags: reference-request, sums-of-squares, translation

Does anyone know if there is a French or English translation of Hilbert's paper on sums of squares: [Ueber die Darstellung definiter Formen als Summe von Formenquadraten](https://eudml.org/doc/157385)?

Comment: Google translate works fine, it starts out like this: _It is well known that any definite quadratic form of $m$ variables can be represented as the sum of $m$ quadratics of real linear forms. In the same way, every definite binary form can be represented as the sum of two squares of real forms, as one recognizes by suitable factor decomposition of the form. Since the presentation in question should reveal the definite character of the form in the simplest conceivable way, a general investigation of the possibility of such representation of interest appears._